# Popular Hibernate applications

Tags: hibernate, orm

I am evaluating a 'taint tracking' technology and am in need of java based, freely available, popular web applications that use hibernate to execute SQL queries against a database. Open source applications would be a plus but not required. All I need to be able to do is start the application, and manually execute some tests and make sure it works.

I have googled 'hibernate applications' but mostly have found tutorials; I need references to  'real world' hibernate based applications.

Also, any other java based ORM/middleware that creates SQL statements from another language like HQL would also be useful.

Thanks
Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spring Petsore:

http://code.google.com/p/spring-petstore/

Also, if using Groovy (dynamic version of Java, runs on JVM) is ok you can create a very simple application that fits all your requirements above in about 50 keystrokes more or less using [Grails](http://grails.org/).